# Should I use long-format or recode the condition column?

Tags: r, dataset

I am just starting out with R and struggling to wrap my head around it.

I have a data set from a $2 \times 2$ repeated measures experiment (IV 1 - Expectation with two levels, number or letter; IV 2 - Target with two levels, number or letter). The dependent variable is reaction time.

I am struggling to decide whether I need to keep my tidied data in a long format with 3 columns - Participant ID, Condition (1, 2, 3, 4), RT. Or recode the condition column into two separate columns so I have four columns in the new tidied data set - ID, Expectation, Target and RT.

Which would be the correct way to go about it? Does it depend on the visualisations I plan to create afterwards?

Hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: To be frank, most of this question doesn't make sense. What happened with IV1 and IV2 - they are not in the data frame? I suggest that you read [how to ask good questions on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Even better might be to practice using R a bit more. I like [Modern Statistics with R](https://www.modernstatisticswithr.com).

Comment: Wow, way to put somebody off who's very new and looking for help. Sort out your attitude - изобщо не съм изненадана, че си българин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell a priori if a long format is better than a wide format since it really depends on what are your aims. Anyway, for modelling purposes, it may be more useful to have it in a long format.

However, note that you can always switch from one format to the other using, for instance, the `reshape` command of `R`.

Comment: Thank you! I have figured it out by myself :) Now I am out of here as some very rude people around. But thank you for being lovely and trying to help!